# TFS 2015 retention policy not applied

Tags: tfs-2015

My build is not specified as retain indefinitely and my build retention policy is 30 days to keep. But still I am able to see builds older than 30 days in Completed builds list.

Could you please help me what might be the reason? I am on TFS 2015 Update 3. Is this a known problem with TFS 2015 Update 3?

Thanks,
Anusha

Answer (score 1):

There is also a `Minimum to keep`, that will result in build being retained longer than the `Days to keep`.